# Permissions for Generated folders and shared volume

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have build a Docker image and uploaded to internal registry.
On Jenkins I pull the image and run the container with `root` user ( `-u root`). I also mount a shared folder from the `${workspace}`
Inside container I run pytest inside the mounted shared folder. This generates temporary `__pycache__` folder and also pytest's report.
But these temporary folders and report are generated with `root` user.

As a result Jenkins is not able to run a cleanup on the workspace due to insufficient privileges on the temporary folder and report file.

I have tried to create a (jenkins) user inside the image itself, but jenkins is unable to run the container when jenkins user is passed as parameter (`-u jenkinsuser`)

I have also tried to `chown` the folders after the test so that I can set specific user and group to the folder but that never runs if test has failed during the run.

Looking forward to guidance from experts here on how to circumvent permission issue with generated folders.

Here is the rough code of the code scripted inside jenkins

```
docker.withRegistry("<server>", "<svc_id>") {
   docker.image('<image_name>').inside('-u root --rm -e <proxy> -e <proxy> --name <mount_name> --mount source=${workspace},target=/app,type=bind') { c ->
                                sh 'echo "Inside container" '
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  If you use [Jenkins's Docker integration](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) and don't try to manually configure anything, `docker.inside(...) { ... }` steps will run with a bind-mounted workspace directory and the same numeric user ID as the worker, so you shouldn't usually have permission problems.

Comment: I have updated the pseudo code. I need to pass the user as "root" has access to python packages that have been installed inside the image. with default user/group I cannot get access to python packages